# Laptop battery indicator blinking red while green

Tags: laptop, battery, power

3 incidents have happened the past week, and I need to decide fast what to do with my new battery that I bought 2 months ago, before the shop warranty expires in less than a month.

1. I was normally working with my laptop, and my battery was fully charged, 100%. And then while the battery indicator was green it started blinking red, so it was red, green, red, green... I unplugged the laptop from charger and then less than a minute later, laptop shut down and when I turned it on, it was 0% on battery and it started charging, I let it charge to 100% and I tested the battery down to 10% without an issue.
2. A day later, laptop was turned on and the same thing - battery indicator starting to blink red while on green light - happened, I unplugged the laptop but immediately plugged it back in and then the red blinking stopped and it became solid green, I unplugged the charger again and started using my laptop on battery for and 1 hour or so until it was on 10% left and I plugged it back in to charge, and it charged normally. Everything was fine.
3. A day later, laptop was unplugged and on Hibernate mode, fully charged from last night. I saw it blinking red (only red, no green because laptop was not plugged in). I turned on the laptop, plugged in the charger immediately, and blinking stopped and battery was on 100%, used the battery without an issue.

What is happening to my laptop or battery? Which is the faulty one? What can I do to fix this? I have an Asus N552VW running on Windows 10. Thanks very much for reading.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it may be the charger itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I let it charge to 100% and I tested the battery down to 10% without
> an issue.

That emulates fairly well a battery reset (not completely but good enough).

> A day later, laptop was turned on and the same thing - battery
> indicator starting to blink red while on green light ... I saw it
> blinking red (only red, no green ...

It appears the battery has an issue, perhaps with the charging circuit in the battery itself.

Take advantage of the warranty and have the battery replaced. Have the machine properly checked with the new battery in case the issue is with the laptop charging circuit including the AC adapter.